# Filter condition =all

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way of creating a filter condition that would be equal to all?

I would like to include all cells with and without cell content as a condition for one of my columns.

It would be something like this
=filter(A1:C4, B1:B4=F2, C1:C4=G2) F2=a & G2='all'

I have set up a spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YVk__M4tZkCqe9ko6pi8MXUHVLGpV6HHYqd59Vw-ps8/edit#gid=0)

The reason why I want to do this is that my condition changes depenedent on other parameters and G2 could be 'all' or a specific condition like 't' but it has cater for both situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to use the filter function but you can add a column that validates your conditions first, then filter on that column only, it would probably be easier

the formula for the validation column could look like this :

`=if(and(B1=$F$2,or(C1=$G$2,C1="")),1,0)`

Comment: Thanks, the supporting column idea gave me enough to work out how to do it in my proper formula, it was really helpful. Thanks a lot again!